# Session is not persistence between adapter and java class (servlet) in mobilefirst server/websphere application server

Tags: session, servlets, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

I am working on mobilefirst 7.1 application which is deployed on websphere application server - network deployment.Earlier version this application is working on worklight 6.1  and everything is working fine.

As per code, we are setting an attribute in session within adapter  and try to access it from java class (servlet) which is part of the application and exposed as servlet using configuration in web.xml file.

My worklight properties configuration :

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession
```

My adapter code :

```
function myProcedure(XXX){
     WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().setAttribute("myAtrrib", XXX);
     return { result :"Success"};
}
```

Java Servlet Code :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String crdAcc = (String) request.getSession(true).getAttribute("myAtrrib");
}
```

So Problem here is when I try to access this attribute it giving me *null*.

As I check the session detail and I found is that session is new session.

I don't know why server is creating new session for this servlet call instead of using same one which is used by mobilefirst adapter. Similar code is working with worklight 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

In a previous question you've mentioned you're on a cluster, so could it be that in your server and/or load balancer, you did not enable the sticky session configuration? This may explain "new connections" happening and values not available.

Comment: To check this what I did, I have stopped one of the server and tested it on only one server. Even though it's not working. Whatever is session data is set from adapter, is accessible from another adapter from session but not from java class(Servlet).

Comment: Consider opening a PMR for IBM Support team to take a look.

Comment: Raised a PMR for that.