# Phonegap childbrowser is invalidating the mobilefirst 7.1 session

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, childbrowser

I am working on mobilefirst 7.1 project which is upgraded from worklight 6.1. We are using childbrowser for showing some pages and for payment.

I found a critical issue that whenever I do payment through child-browser and close the child-browser, application session is no more valid. When I do any secure adapter request it is giving me unauthorization error.My configured session timeout is 5 minutes but it is get invalid even in 1 minute.

I am facing this issue only on ios, in android it is working. In workligh 6.1, it is working on bot environment.

worklight properties :

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession

#Idle session timeout in minutes
serverSessionTimeout=5
```

Childbrowser I am using is older.Here is copyrights:

```
 * Copyright 2012, Andrew Lunny, Adobe Systems
 * Copyright (c) 2005-2010, Nitobi Software Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2011, IBM Corporation
 * (c) 2010 Jesse MacFadyen, Nitobi
```

Answer (score 0):

Please raise this together with the PMR that you intend on opening: [Session is not persistence between adapter and java class (servlet) in mobilefirst server/websphere application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394870/session-is-not-persistence-between-adapter-and-java-class-servlet-in-mobilefir)